# node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I have expo project and i use tamagui and react-native.I am working with Github. When I run npm uninstall expo-font, I got  `node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Unexpected token 'export'`   issue and f in YStack and jc in Paragraph give error.

```
f error :  Type '{ children: Element[]; f: number; jc: string; ai: string; backgroundColor: "$backgroundSoft"; }'** is not assignable to type **'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<ViewProps, "display" | "children" | "style" | "onLayout" | keyof GestureResponderHandlers> & ... 10 more ... & RefAttributes<...>'.**
Property 'f' does not exist on type **'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<ViewProps, "display" | "children" | "style" | "onLayout" | keyof GestureResponderHandlers> & ... 10 more ... & RefAttributes<...>'**.    jc error :  Type 'string' is not assignable to type **'undefined'.ts(2322)**
```

As far as I know, terms like f and jc are defined in Tamagui's own tokens by default.
My codes :
This is **App.tsx:**

```
import { useFonts } from "expo-font"
import React from "react"
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar"
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native"
import { Paragraph, TamaguiProvider, Theme, YStack } from "tamagui"
import config from "./tamagui.config"
export default function App() {
 const colorScheme = useColorScheme()
 const [loaded] = useFonts({
    Urbanist: require("./assets/fonts/Urbanist-Bold.otf"),
    UrbanistSemibold: require("./assets/fonts/Urbanist-SemiBold.otf"),
    UrbanistMedium: require("./assets/fonts/Urbanist-Medium.otf"),
    UrbanistRegular: require("./assets/fonts/Urbanist-Regular.otf"),
  })
 if (!loaded) {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <TamaguiProvider config={config}>
      <Theme name={colorScheme === "dark" ? "dark" : "light"}>
        <YStack
          f={1}
          jc="center"
          ai="center"
          backgroundColor={"$backgroundSoft"}
        >
          <Paragraph color="$color" jc="center">
            {colorScheme}
          </Paragraph>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </YStack>
      </Theme>
    </TamaguiProvider>
  )
}
```

This is **package.json:**

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@tamagui/animations-react-native": "^1.43.13",
    "@tamagui/babel-plugin": "^1.43.13",
    "@tamagui/config": "^1.43.13",
    "@tamagui/font-inter": "^1.43.13",
    "@tamagui/theme-base": "^1.43.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.6",
    "tamagui": "^1.43.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^37.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "prettier": "3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,js,jsx,tsx}": [
      "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --fix --max-warnings 0",
      "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

I deleted node_modules and reinstalled but it didn't work.
I run npx expo install expo-font but it didn't work
I cleared the cache(npm cache clean --force ) but it didn't work.
I merged main and theme branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `type TamaguiCustomConfig = AppConfig` is written in tamagui.config.ts file, replace it with `interface TamaguiCustomConfig extends AppConfig {}` and enter

> // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface as
> eslint comment line.